# Why css and js is not working on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

i am trying for html to wordpress.i called all css and js file.These file are shows in the source in crome.but they are not working.

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300i,400,400i,600,700,800%7CMontserrat:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css' ,  ' ', '1.1' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/animate.css' ,  ' ', '1.1');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'text', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/text-animation.css' ,  ' ', '1.1');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fancy', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/jquery.fancybox.min.css' ,  ' ', '1.1');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'magnific',get_template_directory_uri()  . '/assets/css/magnific-popup.min.css' , ' ', '1.1');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl', get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css' ,  ' ', '1.1');
   wp_enqueue_style( 'icons',get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/css/icons.css' , ' ', '1.1');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'menu',get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/css/menu-css.css' ,  ' ', '1.1');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/css/main.css' ,  ' ', '1.1');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'responsiv',get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/css/responsive.css' ,  ' ', '1.1');

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquerymini', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery.min.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'minmodernizr', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/modernizr.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'waypoints', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/waypoints.min.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'minbootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'minplugin', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/plugins.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'minscrollup', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery.scrollUp.min.js' , ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'googlemap','https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB4RM7zOgOKq6n2fv407hX28xiL-M6vLdY');
wp_enqueue_script( 'gmap', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/gmaps.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'minfancybox', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'popup', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' , ' ', '1.1' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'isotop', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'counterup', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/counterup.min.js' , ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'owl', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'wow', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/wow.min.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'lettering', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery.lettering.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'textillate', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery.textillate.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script('mixitup', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/mixitup.js' , ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'chart', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/chart.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'active', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/chart-active.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'tool', get_template_directory_uri().'/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'revolution', get_template_directory_uri().'/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'actions', get_template_directory_uri().'/rs-plugin/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js' , ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'kenburn', get_template_directory_uri().'/rs-plugin/js/extensions/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'layeranimation', get_template_directory_uri().'/rs-plugin/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'migration', get_template_directory_uri().'/rs-plugin/js/extensions/revolution.extension.migration.min.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'navigation', get_template_directory_uri().'/rs-plugin/js/extensions/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'parallax', get_template_directory_uri().'/rs-plugin/js/extensions/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'slide', get_template_directory_uri().'/rs-plugin/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js' ,  ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'video', get_template_directory_uri().'/rs-plugin/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js' , ' ', '1.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri().'assets/js/custom.js' ,' ', '1.1');
```

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'consult_css_js') ;

Comment: can you post your website to let us better understand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your files and did you check that the paths are correct?

Enqueue style

```
wp_register_style('name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/name.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
wp_enqueue_style('name'); // Enqueue it!
```

Enqueue JS

```
wp_register_script('name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/name.js', array(), '4.3.0'); 
wp_enqueue_script('name'); // Enqueue it!
```